# submitting dynamically created form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I'm attempting to submit a form I've created out of an html string, like this:

```
        var upload_form = "`<form action=\"uploadSong.php\" method=\"POST\" class=\"upload_form\" enctype = \"multipart/form-data\" target=\"upload_form\">`";

        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"showId\" value=\"" + showId + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"band_abb\" value=\"" + band_abb + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"showDate\" value=\"" + date + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"city\" value=\"" + city + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"state\" value=\"" + state + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"venue\" value=\"" + venue + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"setNum\" value=\"" + setNum + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"songNum\" value=\"" + songNum + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"songId\" value=\"" + songId + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"showId\" value=\"" + showId + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"songName\" value=\"" + songName + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"file\" name=\"upload[]\" value=\"" + songLoc + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"partOfASegue\" value=\"" + partOfASeuge + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"addInfo\" value=\"" + addInfo + "\" />";
        upload_form += "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_btn\" value=\"submited\" />";
        upload_form += "</form>";

        $('#upload_form').html(upload_form);

        alert(upload_form);

        $('form .upload_form').submit();

        $('form .upload_form').remove();
```

And I have a target for the html like this:

```
`<iframe id="upload_form"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to repetitively upload a series of files, Does anyone see why this wouldn't work?

Comment: removing space between 'form' and '.upload_form' didn't help :(

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, but I think browser security settings normally will not allow you to set the contents of <input type="file" /> programmatically, resulting in some security exception when you submit.

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It's a valid concern, though probably not what's affecting OP's current problem

Answer (score 2):

The only thing i see that wouldn't work is the selector for the submit call.

you have:

```
$('form .upload_form').submit();
$('form .upload_form').remove();
```

what it should be:

```
$('form.upload_form').submit().remove();
```

Also, from this line in your code:

```
$('#upload_form').html(upload_form);
```

I would infer that you have a container with the id of `upload_form`, but your iframe also has the same id. I suggest you change one of the id's otherwise you might get glitchy behaviour.

To summarize my the changes would look like:

HTML:

```
<div id="uploadFormContainer"></div>
<iframe id="upload_form"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
var upload_form = ... /* your form string unchanged - excluded for brevity */

$('#uploadFormContainer').html(upload_form);

alert(upload_form);

$('form.upload_form').submit().remove();
```

Comment: Or `$('#upload_form').html(upload_form).children().submit().remove()` ...if you really wanted to

Comment: I'm trying to add the form into the <iframe>, would that be incorrect?

Comment: oh, i had the impression that you were just posting to the iframe. In that case you don't need to rename anything, just change the selector. And make sure that the iframe exists in the DOM before you add the form. And that you have all the proper HTML surrounding the form like: <html><head><title></title><body>your form here</body></html>

Comment: oops missed the closing </head> but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery selector is wrong.  You need to remove the space character, like so:

```
$('form.upload_form')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider rewriting your code a bit to avoid the use of needless selectors.  Example:

```
//assuming upload_form is defined as it is in the question

//build a DOM/jQuery node from the html string
upload_form = $(upload_form);

//set the contents of #upload_form to the upload form
$('#upload_form').empty().append(upload_form);

//submit the form
upload_form.submit();

//delete the form
upload_form.remove();
```

As others have mentioned, you can chain the jQuery calls as well, and use something like `upload_form.submit().remove();`